# Getting the right font for ptm/n/n in IEEE Access Template

Tags: fonts, templates, ieeeaccess

I am using the latex template of IEEE ACCESS (i.e., `\documentclass{ieeeaccess}`)officially provided by the IEEE template selector. However, when compiling I get the warning that certain fonts are missing.

> Font shape 'T1/ptm/n/n' undefined 
> (Font) using `T1/ptm/m/n' instead.

> Font shape 'T1/phv/n/n' undefined 
> (Font) using `T1/phv/m/n' instead.

And I dig into the log file, which shows:

> LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for T1+ptm on input line 36.
> ("/Users/***/Library/Application Support/MiKTeX/texmfs/install/tex/latex/psnfss/**t1ptm.fd**"
> File: t1ptm.fd 2001/06/04 font definitions for **T1/ptm**.

> LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for T1+phv on input line 55.
> ("/Users/hurunqiu/Library/Application Support/MiKTeX/texmfs/install/tex/latex/psnfss/**t1phv.fd**"
> File: t1phv.fd 2020/03/25 scalable font definitions for **T1/phv**.
> )

I suppose pdfLaTeX is searching the fonts in T1/ptm and T1/phv. Looking inside one of the two files(T1/ptm.td) I found:

```tex
\ProvidesFile{t1ptm.fd}
   [2001/06/04 font definitions for T1/ptm.]

\DeclareFontFamily{T1}{ptm}{}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}{
   <-> ptmr8t
}{}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{ptm}{m}{sc}{
   <-> ptmrc8t
}{}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{ptm}{m}{sl}{
   <-> ptmro8t
}{}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{ptm}{m}{it}{
   <-> ptmri8t
}{}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{ptm}{b}{n}{
   <-> ptmb8t
}{}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{ptm}{b}{sc}{
   <-> ptmbc8t
}{}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{ptm}{b}{sl}{
   <-> ptmbo8t
}{}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{ptm}{b}{it}{
   <-> ptmbi8t
}{}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{ptm}{bx}{n}{<->ssub * ptm/b/n}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{ptm}{bx}{sc}{<->ssub * ptm/b/sc}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{ptm}{bx}{sl}{<->ssub * ptm/b/sl}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{ptm}{bx}{it}{<->ssub * ptm/b/it}{}

\endinput
```

There is indeed no combination of ptm/n/n.

Meanwhile, I checked `ieeeaccess.cls` provided by official, and found one line `\def\bioaddressfont{\sffamily\putfont{T1}{formata}{n}{n}{8}{10}}`.

I believe it's here that requires the font `ptm/n/n` and `phv/n/n`.

I thought I could neglect the warning if the substituted fonts are OK. However, seeing the published paper, I found the font of the bold titles(including subsections) are indeed different from mine now:

The published articles: [image]

Mine currently: [image]

I think I shouldn't change the template, and I found no ptm/n/n font solutions online, so where went wrong? How can I make it right?

(P.S. I have tried both pdfLatex and MiKteX, and both couldn't work.)

Comment: Wow, that class (at least the one I found on github) contains a lot of `\fontseries{n}` instructions. That's utter nonsense.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Note that if your paper gets published then the editors of the journal will fix this kind of issues to make all papers are conforming to the official template, therefore you don't necessarily need to fix this yourself.

Comment: @campa Yes. I think `n/n` makes no sense since I found a lot of people unable to find `m/n`. I literally don't know how the template was given. BTW, what do these parameters mean, especially the last two slashes?

Comment: @Marijn That might be true, but a journal template with font errors and an official template which yields dozens of bad boxes is quite depressing... BobHU Explaining font selection is too long for a comment you might want to give a look at section 2 of the [LaTeX font guide](https://www.latex-project.org/help/documentation/fntguide.pdf).