# IEEE Access latex template fonts

Tags: fonts, pdftex, ieeeaccess

I cannot get the right fonts for headings using ieeeaccess document class. It would seem that I do not have the right fonts installed. The warning message:

```
pdfTeX warning: pdflatex.exe (file t1-times.map): cannot open font map file

pdfTeX warning: pdflatex.exe (file t1-formata.map): cannot open font map file

pdfTeX warning: pdflatex.exe (file t1-giovannistd.map): cannot open font map file
```

Followed by several others where it says that default fonts were selected.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{ieeeaccess}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\hyphenation{op-tical net-works semi-conduc-tor IEEE-Xplore}
\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
    T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}

\begin{document}

\history{Date of publication xxxx 00, 0000, date of current version xxxx 00, 0000.}
\doi{10.1109/ACCESS.2017.DOI}

\title{Sample title}

\author{\uppercase{First author}\authorrefmark{1}, \IEEEmembership{Student Member, IEEE},
\uppercase{Second author\authorrefmark{2}}, \uppercase{Third author}\authorrefmark{1},
\IEEEmembership{Student Member, IEEE}, \uppercase{and Fourth author}\authorrefmark{1},
\IEEEmembership{Fellow, IEEE}}
\address[1]{First sample address}
\address[2]{Second sample address}
\tfootnote{This work was supported by sample funding}

\markboth
{F. Author \headeretal: Sample title}
{F. Author \headeretal: Sample title}

\corresp{Corresponding author: First author (e-mail:).}

\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{abstract}


\begin{keywords}
Sample key words.
\end{keywords}

\titlepgskip=-15pt

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[1-5]

\section{Conclusion}
\lipsum[1-1]

\EOD

\end{document}
```

IEEE Access template together with required PNGs for the MWE can be downloaded from the official IEEE website: https://journals.ieeeauthorcenter.ieee.org/create-your-ieee-journal-article/authoring-tools-and-templates/tools-for-ieee-authors/ieee-article-templates/. Navigate: IEEE Template Selector > Transcations, Journals and Letters > IEEE Access > Original Research > LaTeX > Download Template.

Full build output:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.23 (MiKTeX 21.10) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2021.12.6)  6 DEC 2021 21:41
entering extended mode
**./MWE.tex
(MWE.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-11-15>
L3 programming layer <2021-11-22> (ieeeaccess.cls
(C:\Users\pv30\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/ieeetran\IEEEtran.cls
Document Class: IEEEtran 2015/08/26 V1.8b by Michael Shell
-- See the "IEEEtran_HOWTO" manual for usage information.
-- http://www.michaelshell.org/tex/ieeetran/
\@IEEEtrantmpdimenA=\dimen138
\@IEEEtrantmpdimenB=\dimen139
\@IEEEtrantmpdimenC=\dimen140
\@IEEEtrantmpcountA=\count183
\@IEEEtrantmpcountB=\count184
\@IEEEtrantmpcountC=\count185
\@IEEEtrantmptoksA=\toks16
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for OT1+ptm on input line 503.
(C:\Users\pv30\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/psnfss\ot1ptm.fd
File: ot1ptm.fd 2001/06/04 font definitions for OT1/ptm.
)
-- Using 8.5in x 11in (letter) paper.
-- Using PDF output.
\@IEEEnormalsizeunitybaselineskip=\dimen141
-- This is a 10 point document.
\CLASSINFOnormalsizebaselineskip=\dimen142
\CLASSINFOnormalsizeunitybaselineskip=\dimen143
\IEEEnormaljot=\dimen144
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/n' in size <5> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/n' tried instead on input line 1090.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/it' in size <5> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/it' tried instead on input line 1090.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/n' in size <7> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/n' tried instead on input line 1090.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/it' in size <7> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/it' tried instead on input line 1090.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/n' in size <8> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/n' tried instead on input line 1090.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/it' in size <8> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/it' tried instead on input line 1090.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/n' in size <9> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/n' tried instead on input line 1090.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/it' in size <9> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/it' tried instead on input line 1090.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/n' in size <10> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/n' tried instead on input line 1090.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/it' in size <10> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/it' tried instead on input line 1090.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/n' in size <11> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/n' tried instead on input line 1090.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/it' in size <11> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/it' tried instead on input line 1090.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/n' in size <12> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/n' tried instead on input line 1090.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/it' in size <12> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/it' tried instead on input line 1090.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/n' in size <17> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/n' tried instead on input line 1090.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/it' in size <17> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/it' tried instead on input line 1090.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/n' in size <20> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/n' tried instead on input line 1090.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/it' in size <20> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/it' tried instead on input line 1090.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/n' in size <24> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/n' tried instead on input line 1090.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/it' in size <24> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/it' tried instead on input line 1090.
\IEEEquantizedlength=\dimen145
\IEEEquantizedlengthdiff=\dimen146
\IEEEquantizedtextheightdiff=\dimen147
\IEEEilabelindentA=\dimen148
\IEEEilabelindentB=\dimen149
\IEEEilabelindent=\dimen150
\IEEEelabelindent=\dimen151
\IEEEdlabelindent=\dimen152
\IEEElabelindent=\dimen153
\IEEEiednormlabelsep=\dimen154
\IEEEiedmathlabelsep=\dimen155
\IEEEiedtopsep=\skip47
\c@section=\count186
\c@subsection=\count187
\c@subsubsection=\count188
\c@paragraph=\count189
\c@IEEEsubequation=\count190
\abovecaptionskip=\skip48
\belowcaptionskip=\skip49
\c@figure=\count191
\c@table=\count192
\@IEEEeqnnumcols=\count193
\@IEEEeqncolcnt=\count194
\@IEEEsubeqnnumrollback=\count195
\@IEEEquantizeheightA=\dimen156
\@IEEEquantizeheightB=\dimen157
\@IEEEquantizeheightC=\dimen158
\@IEEEquantizeprevdepth=\dimen159
\@IEEEquantizemultiple=\count196
\@IEEEquantizeboxA=\box50
\@IEEEtmpitemindent=\dimen160
\IEEEPARstartletwidth=\dimen161
\c@IEEEbiography=\count197
\@IEEEtranrubishbin=\box51
) (C:\Users\pv30\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/iftex\ifpdf.sty
Package: ifpdf 2019/10/25 v3.4 ifpdf legacy package. Use iftex instead.

(C:\Users\pv30\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/iftex\iftex.sty
Package: iftex 2020/03/06 v1.0d TeX engine tests
))
(C:\Users\pv30\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/xkeyval\xkeyval.sty
Package: xkeyval 2020/11/20 v2.8 package option processing (HA)

(C:\Users\pv30\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/xkeyval\xkeyval.tex
(C:\Users\pv30\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/xkeyval\xkvutils.tex
\XKV@toks=\toks17
\XKV@tempa@toks=\toks18

(C:\Users\pv30\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/xkeyval\keyval.tex))
\XKV@depth=\count198
File: xkeyval.tex 2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
)){C:/Users/pv30/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}

pdfTeX warning: pdflatex.exe (file t1-times.map): cannot open font map file


pdfTeX warning: pdflatex.exe (file t1-formata.map): cannot open font map file


pdfTeX warning: pdflatex.exe (file t1-giovannistd.map): cannot open font map file
\@draftversionrule=\dimen162
(C:\Users\pv30\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\color.sty
Package: color 2021/10/11 v1.3b Standard LaTeX Color (DPC)

(C:\Users\pv30\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics-cfg\color.cfg
File: color.cfg 2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
)
Package color Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 149.

(C:\Users\pv30\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics-def\pdftex.def
File: pdftex.def 2020/10/05 v1.2a Graphics/color driver for pdftex
))
(C:\Users\pv30\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\spotcolor.sty
Package: spotcolor 2006/11/15 v1.2 Package for adding Spot Color support to pdfLaTeX.

(C:\Users\pv30\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2021/03/04 v1.4d Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(C:\Users\pv30\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\trig.sty
Package: trig 2021/08/11 v1.11 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
(C:\Users\pv30\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics-cfg\graphics.cfg
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 107.
)
\thecolorprofile=\count199
\thecolor=\count266
)
\PANTONE=\toks19
Package color Info: Redefining color black on input line 135.
\figbox=\box52
\titlewidth=\skip50
\abstractwidth=\skip51
\c@addrCtr=\count267
\abstractbox=\box53
\indexbox=\box54
\absht=\dimen163
\kwdht=\dimen164
\@tempcntc=\count268
\titlepgskip=\skip52
\maketitlebox=\box55
)
(C:\Users\pv30\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/cite\cite.sty
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cite on input line 302.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \nocite on input line 332.
Package: cite 2015/02/27  v 5.5
)
(C:\Users\pv30\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amsmath\amsmath.sty
Package: amsmath 2021/10/15 v2.17l AMS math features
\@mathmargin=\skip53

For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(C:\Users\pv30\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amsmath\amstext.sty
Package: amstext 2021/08/26 v2.01 AMS text

(C:\Users\pv30\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amsmath\amsgen.sty
File: amsgen.sty 1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
\@emptytoks=\toks20
\ex@=\dimen165
))
(C:\Users\pv30\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amsmath\amsbsy.sty
Package: amsbsy 1999/11/29 v1.2d Bold Symbols
\pmbraise@=\dimen166
)
(C:\Users\pv30\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amsmath\amsopn.sty
Package: amsopn 2021/08/26 v2.02 operator names
)
\inf@bad=\count269
LaTeX Info: Redefining \frac on input line 234.
\uproot@=\count270
\leftroot@=\count271
LaTeX Info: Redefining \overline on input line 399.
\classnum@=\count272
\DOTSCASE@=\count273
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ldots on input line 496.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \dots on input line 499.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cdots on input line 620.
\Mathstrutbox@=\box56
\strutbox@=\box57
\big@size=\dimen167
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OML on input line 743.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OMS on input line 744.
\macc@depth=\count274
\c@MaxMatrixCols=\count275
\dotsspace@=\muskip16
\c@parentequation=\count276
\dspbrk@lvl=\count277
\tag@help=\toks21
\row@=\count278
\column@=\count279
\maxfields@=\count280
\andhelp@=\toks22
\eqnshift@=\dimen168
\alignsep@=\dimen169
\tagshift@=\dimen170
\tagwidth@=\dimen171
\totwidth@=\dimen172
\lineht@=\dimen173
\@envbody=\toks23
\multlinegap=\skip54
\multlinetaggap=\skip55
\mathdisplay@stack=\toks24
LaTeX Info: Redefining \[ on input line 2938.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \] on input line 2939.
)
(C:\Users\pv30\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amsfonts\amssymb.sty
Package: amssymb 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS font symbols

(C:\Users\pv30\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amsfonts\amsfonts.sty
Package: amsfonts 2013/01/14 v3.01 Basic AMSFonts support
\symAMSa=\mathgroup4
\symAMSb=\mathgroup5
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \hbar on input line 98.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathfrak' in version `bold'
(Font)                  U/euf/m/n --> U/euf/b/n on input line 106.
))
(C:\Users\pv30\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/algorithms\algorithmic.sty
Package: algorithmic 2009/08/24 v0.1 Document Style `algorithmic'

(C:\Users\pv30\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\ifthen.sty
Package: ifthen 2020/11/24 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
)
\c@ALC@unique=\count281
\c@ALC@line=\count282
\c@ALC@rem=\count283
\c@ALC@depth=\count284
\ALC@tlm=\skip56
\algorithmicindent=\skip57
)
(C:\Users\pv30\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\graphicx.sty
Package: graphicx 2021/09/16 v1.2d Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
\Gin@req@height=\dimen174
\Gin@req@width=\dimen175
)
(C:\Users\pv30\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\textcomp.sty
Package: textcomp 2020/02/02 v2.0n Standard LaTeX package
)
(C:\Users\pv30\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/lipsum\lipsum.sty
(C:\Users\pv30\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3packages/l3keys2e\l3keys2e.sty
(C:\Users\pv30\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3kernel\expl3.sty
Package: expl3 2021-11-22 L3 programming layer (loader) 

(C:\Users\pv30\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3backend\l3backend-pdftex.def
File: l3backend-pdftex.def 2021-10-18 L3 backend support: PDF output (pdfTeX)
\l__color_backend_stack_int=\count285
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box58
))
Package: l3keys2e 2021-11-12 LaTeX2e option processing using LaTeX3 keys
)
Package: lipsum 2021-09-20 v2.7 150 paragraphs of Lorem Ipsum dummy text
\g__lipsum_par_int=\count286
\l__lipsum_a_int=\count287
\l__lipsum_b_int=\count288

(C:\Users\pv30\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/lipsum\lipsum.ltd.tex)) (MWE.aux)
\openout1 = `MWE.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 13.

-- Lines per column: 56 (exact).
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for T1+ptm on input line 13.
(C:\Users\pv30\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/psnfss\t1ptm.fd
File: t1ptm.fd 2001/06/04 font definitions for T1/ptm.
)

LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T1/ptm/n/n' undefined
(Font)              using `T1/ptm/m/n' instead on input line 13.

(C:\Users\pv30\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/context/base/mkii\supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
\scratchcounter=\count289
\scratchdimen=\dimen176
\scratchbox=\box59
\nofMPsegments=\count290
\nofMParguments=\count291
\everyMPshowfont=\toks25
\MPscratchCnt=\count292
\MPscratchDim=\dimen177
\MPnumerator=\count293
\makeMPintoPDFobject=\count294
\everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks26
) (C:\Users\pv30\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg\epstopdf-base.sty
Package: epstopdf-base 2020-01-24 v2.11 Base part for package epstopdf
Package epstopdf-base Info: Redefining graphics rule for `.eps' on input line 485.

(C:\Users\pv30\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/00miktex\epstopdf-sys.cfg
File: epstopdf-sys.cfg 2021/03/18 v2.0 Configuration of epstopdf for MiKTeX
))
<bullet.png, id=3, 12.045pt x 35.38219pt>
File: bullet.png Graphic file (type png)
<use bullet.png>
Package pdftex.def Info: bullet.png  used on input line 34.
(pdftex.def)             Requested size: 5.0pt x 14.6871pt.
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for T1+phv on input line 34.

(C:\Users\pv30\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/psnfss\t1phv.fd
File: t1phv.fd 2020/03/25 scalable font definitions for T1/phv.
)

LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T1/phv/n/n' undefined
(Font)              using `T1/phv/m/n' instead on input line 34.

File: bullet.png Graphic file (type png)
<use bullet.png>
Package pdftex.def Info: bullet.png  used on input line 39.
(pdftex.def)             Requested size: 5.0pt x 14.6871pt.
LaTeX Font Info:    Calculating math sizes for size <9.9> on input line 45.
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for U+msa on input line 45.
(C:\Users\pv30\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amsfonts\umsa.fd
File: umsa.fd 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols A
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for U+msb on input line 45.

(C:\Users\pv30\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amsfonts\umsb.fd
File: umsb.fd 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols B
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Calculating math sizes for size <6.6> on input line 45.

Overfull \hbox (9.2679pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 45--45
[]  
 []


Overfull \hbox (9.2679pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 45--45
[]  
 []


Underfull \vbox (badness 1845) has occurred while \output is active []


Underfull \vbox (badness 1845) has occurred while \output is active []

<logo.png, id=4, 206.27063pt x 53.44969pt>
File: logo.png Graphic file (type png)
<use logo.png>
Package pdftex.def Info: logo.png  used on input line 49.
(pdftex.def)             Requested size: 91.32pt x 23.66309pt.

Overfull \hbox (505.12177pt too wide) has occurred while \output is active
[]
 []


Overfull \hbox (505.12177pt too wide) has occurred while \output is active
[]
 []


Overfull \hbox (505.12177pt too wide) has occurred while \output is active
[]
 []


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active
[]
 []

[1


 <./logo.png> <./bullet.png>]
File: bullet.png Graphic file (type png)
<use bullet.png>
Package pdftex.def Info: bullet.png  used on input line 53.
(pdftex.def)             Requested size: 5.0pt x 14.6871pt.
<notaglinelogo.png, id=13, 169.38281pt x 42.91031pt>
File: notaglinelogo.png Graphic file (type png)
<use notaglinelogo.png>
Package pdftex.def Info: notaglinelogo.png  used on input line 55.
(pdftex.def)             Requested size: 91.32pt x 23.1352pt.

Overfull \hbox (505.12177pt too wide) has occurred while \output is active
[]
 []


Overfull \hbox (505.12177pt too wide) has occurred while \output is active
[]
 []


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active
[]
 []

[2

 <./notaglinelogo.png>] (MWE.aux)

LaTeX Font Warning: Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.

 ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 4817 strings out of 478681
 81974 string characters out of 2847009
 471836 words of memory out of 3000000
 22837 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 469620 words of font info for 121 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1145 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 70i,12n,77p,225b,407s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
{C:/Users/pv30/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/fonts/enc/dvips/base/8r.enc}<C:/Users/pv30/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/
fonts/type1/urw/helvetic/uhvb8a.pfb><C:/Users/pv30/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/fonts/type1/urw/helvetic/uhvr8a.pfb><C:
/Users/pv30/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/fonts/type1/urw/helvetic/uhvro8a.pfb><C:/Users/pv30/AppData/Local/Programs/MiK
TeX/fonts/type1/urw/times/utmr8a.pfb><C:/Users/pv30/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/fonts/type1/urw/times/utmri8a.pfb>
Output written on MWE.pdf (2 pages, 68861 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 40 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 24 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

Operating system: Windows 10

LaTeX distribution: MikTeX

LaTeX front-end: TeXnicCenter

Similar questions:

[\textsc in IEEE Access Template](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/472425/textsc-in-ieee-access-template)

[Getting the right font for ptm/n/n in IEEE Access Template](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/572174/getting-the-right-font-for-ptm-n-n-in-ieee-access-template)

Things I've tried:
As suggested by the answer in the first question above, I contacted the journal, but they said "Thank you again for contacting us. Because this is not an issue particular to our LaTeX template but to LaTeX in general, it is best addressed by posting on one or both of the LaTeX forums:  https://latex.org/forum/ and/or https://tex.stackexchange.com/"

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: The warnings are annoying but more or less harmless. Your document compiles. When you upload the article they will perhaps exchange the fonts with local ones by providing the maps, but you could ask the author of the template for confirmation.